# How to set value of the current row based on data from the next row in a datagridview using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I had this problem setting a cell value based on the value of the next row.

For example;

```
 Remarks    Reference
   A           50
   A           25
   B            5
              -25
```

CASE 1:

If the value of the Next Cell.Row in column "Reference" is a POSITIVE number then the value of cell.row in column "Remarks" is "A".

CASE 2:

If the value of the Next Cell.Row in column "Reference" is a NEGATIVE number then the value of cell.row in column "Remarks" is "B".

I already tried this code but i cannot get the result i need.

```
    Dim Bal As Decimal = 0
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvSTSub.Rows
        Bal = Bal + r.Cells(3).Value - r.Cells(1).Value
        r.Cells(3).Value = Bal

        If Bal > 0 Then
            r.Cells(2).Value = Bal
        ElseIf Bal < 0 Then
            r.Cells(2).Value = r.Cells(3).Value
        End If
    Next
```

Please share me a code on how to do it.

Comment: Use `for` loop instead of `foreach`. Also, access the cell values based on `Column names` , instead of their index. As per my understanding of your question, you want to manipulate current row based on values from the Next Row, right?

Comment: I addressed this same question elsewhere and that seems to have been ignored.  Please don't ignore this one too.  Either use a `For` loop instead of a `For Each` loop, in which case accessing and adjacent row is a simple matter of either incrementing or decrementing the loop counter, or get the `Index` property of the current row and do the same to it.  The first option is better because then you can easily start with the second row or end with the second last row.

Comment: I'm sorry if i ignored your suggestion a while back, I'm just new in vb.net.. In fact i replied earlier to share me some code because i do not know how to do it. I cannot figure it out the logic. my apologies bro. thanks for the help.

Comment: Any way.. Thank you for your suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd recommend using `For` loop instead of `ForEach` because iterating over rows becomes more convenient and easy.

Secondly, use `ColumnNames` instead of `Index` while accessing `.Cells`, for eg: use `.Cells("reference")`(*reference* is Column Name) instead of `.Cells(1)`. I'm suggesting this because if in future you happen to re-order the columns your methods and functions won't get hindered, unless you change the name of your column. 
Note: ColumnName here is not the the Header Text you see in the DataGridView UI. (hope you already know that)

As you haven't shown where you are setting remarks, this should get you some idea how to achieve it:

```
For index = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
   Dim nxt = 1 
   If (index + 1 < DataGridView1.RowCount) Then
        nxt = DataGridView1.Rows(index + 1).Cells("reference").Value
   End If
   If (nxt) > 0 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells("remark").Value = "A"
   Else
        DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells("remark").Value = "B"
   End If
Next
```

Dummy Output:

```
Remark    Reference

A        13
B        21
A       -33
B        41
A       -54
```

Comment: Ow yes! that is what i'm talking about..!!!!! You're an angle bro.. THank you... simple as that..Thank you so much..